# document.ready() after refreshing page (with different param)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 'index.php' file, and the file contains JavaScript code like below

```
$( "#button1" ).mouseup(function() {
    temp = 1;
    vol = 2;
    if (temp != 0 && vol != 0){
        window.location.href = "index.php?temp=" + temp + "&vol=" + vol;
        return;
    }
});
```

Because of this code, the page now redirect to

```
http://localhost/index.php?temp=1&vol=2
```

I would like to check the url parameter in documnet.ready() function (or anywhere) because I have to use the temp & vol value in somewhere.

But the problem is document.ready() function does not execute. I also tried window.load() function..

Any idea?

**Addition**

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    var temp = getQueryVariable("temp");
    var vol = getQueryVariable("vol");
    if (temp != 0 && vol != 0){         
        $("#section1").css("display","block");      
        $("#section2").css("display","none");                   
    }
});
```

Basically, it will check the parameter named 'temp' and 'vol'. If those param exists, then decision on displaying blocks will be changed.

Note that I also tried with $(document).ready(function());

**Addition2**

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
   }
   return(false);
}
```

This function was copied from

```
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/
```

**Addition3**

To explain the purpose of this whole code is..
1) User **changes** numerical value (temp and vol)
2) When hit 'submit', it calls $("#button1").mouseup(function()) JavaScript function above.
3) In the mouseup() function, I need to call **PHP** function with two param (temp and vol)

PHP does not allow me to use JavaScript value, so I am trying to reload the page with param, and would like to use the param value to call the PHP function. But, again, the problem is document.ready() or window.load() function is not executed.

Comment: it should be `$(document).ready()`, isn't it?

Comment: any error in your browser console?... also share your ready function

Comment: Might be you forgot to include `jquery.js` in your code. Show your code with `document.ready`.

Comment: Yes, syntax is fine.. $(document).ready() & $(window).load..
I added more code for your information!

Comment: @Sadikhasan  jquery.js should be there since $( "#button1" ).mouseup(function()) is working?

Comment: @Adrian Can post `getQueryVariable();` ?

Comment: can you add some console logging/alert stmts in teh dom ready hanlder and log the values of temp & vol

Comment: What is expected result of `temp != 0` ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny, document.ready() function is not executed once the page is reloaded with additional ?temp=10&vol=5 param.

Comment: @guest271314 expected result of temp does not matter, as I explained above. document.ready or window.load function is not even executed

Comment: @Adrian and there is no error in your console... can you add an alert before the `$(document).ready()`... so that we can make sure teh dom ready handler is getting registered